# слайдер bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, slider

Как реализовать слайдер bootstrap для изображений разной пропорции которые загружают пользователи? Сейчас при смене кадра, слайдер либо меняет размер либо виден серый фон слайдера для маленьких картинок.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, отображать загружаемые картинки в виде фона с background-size: cover